# Is there a way I can resolve this error message?

Tags: r

I have checked on meta but was still unable to find a lead to the solution. Please is there anything else I can do because I have installed **tidyverse** and **dplyr** yet my code keeps giving error. When I searched for **?slice_sample** in help, I could not find it in help. Can somebody please tell me what to do?

```
 > reduced <- powerData %>% filter(marker == "Natural") %>% slice_sample(prop = 0.8)
 Error in slice_sample(., prop = 0.8) : 
 could not find function "slice_sample"
 > getAnywhere(slice_sample)
 no object named ‘slice_sample’ was found
 > getAnywhere(slice_sample)
 no object named ‘slice_sample’ was found
 > help.search("slice_sample") # nothing came out
```

Comment: `slice_sample` is a new function in `dplyr` 1.0.0. What is your `packageVersion('dplyr')` ?

Comment: You say that you _installed_  `dplyer` but did you also _load_ it by running `library(dplyer)` ?

Comment: I installed and loaded it

Comment: try with dplyr::slice_sample(prop = 0.8)?

Comment: @RonakShah > packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.8.5’

Comment: So that answers the question since you need `dplyr 1.0.0` to access the function. Do `install.packages('dplyr')`, load it with `library(dplyr)` and try again.

Comment: @RonakShah. I have tried to reinstall it but it's giving me this error message.                         > install.packages("dplyr")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Restarting R session...

Comment: @Researchman that's because you're trying to reinstall dplyr with the package already loaded. Open a fresh session and run `install.packages("dplyr")`